# How to know if another thread does SynchronousQueue poll?

Tags: java, asynchronous, java.util.concurrent, thread-synchronization

I have very obscure use case but in essence I need to know if another thread does SynchronousQueue `poll` (with timeout) and it it does I want to insert item and unblock it.

Is there any straightforward way to do that? From my naive read code of javadoc and code it seems like no but I thought I would check wiht SOE.

Comment: you can extend SynchronousQueue and override the poll(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) method to do whatever you want and call the super class method

Comment: @孙兴斌 I should have clarified - another thread does poll with timeout.

Comment: @bl3e at point where I want to do something another thread certainly in blocked state (eg. called `poll`) and I can do little with override is super.poll already called (technically I can do thread interrupt but I would rather not).

Comment: If you could use a subclass then the thread calling poll of the inherited class(say NotifyOnPollSynchronousQueue) won't go in blocking state until it calls poll of it's super class ,i.e SynchronousQueue

Comment: @bl3e I had working solution with subclass but it ended up very simple solution with build-in method from SQ - please take a look into my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after number of solutions (custom queue, separate volatile variable to track insertion) it ended up very simple solution with using `offer` method:

```
/**
 * Inserts the specified element into this queue, if another thread is
 * waiting to receive it.
 *
 * @param e the element to add
 * @return {@code true} if the element was added to this queue, else
 *         {@code false}
 * @throws NullPointerException if the specified element is null
 */
public boolean offer(E e) {
    if (e == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    return transferer.transfer(e, true, 0) != null;
}
```

If I just do `if(offer(e)) ... else ...` that helps unblock consumer if any.

Answer (score 0):

What if you implemented this logic and your producer thread adds value to the queue each time it finds out there is another thread blocked on `poll` - where is guarantee that the value you producer puts into queue will be consumed by that thread and not another ?

Suggest to change you design. Producer - the thread that adds values to queue - should know nothing about consumers. Make you produces a request consumer. I mean define another queue and make your current thread that makes `poll` submits a `request`. And you current producer thread takes requests from that new queue and fulfils request. You can implement request object the way that it works as *mediator* between two threads.